# TensorFlow 1.x: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, tflearn

I am new to TensorFlow. I made the following Neural Network in TensorFlow 1.x

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import tflearn

class ActorNetwork(object):
    """
    Input to the network is the state, output is the action
    under a deterministic policy.
    The output layer activation is a tanh to keep the action
    between -action_bound and action_bound
    """

    def __init__(self, sess, state_dim, action_dim, action_bound, learning_rate, tau, batch_size):
        self.sess = sess
        self.s_dim = state_dim
        self.a_dim = action_dim
        self.action_bound = action_bound
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.tau = tau
        self.batch_size = batch_size

        # Actor Network
        self.inputs, self.out, self.scaled_out = self.create_actor_network()

        self.network_params = tf.trainable_variables()

        # Target Network
        self.target_inputs, self.target_out, self.target_scaled_out = self.create_actor_network()

        self.target_network_params = tf.trainable_variables()[
            len(self.network_params):]

        # Op for periodically updating target network with online network
        # weights
        self.update_target_network_params = \
            [self.target_network_params[i].assign(tf.multiply(self.network_params[i], self.tau) +
                                                  tf.multiply(self.target_network_params[i], 1. - self.tau))
                for i in range(len(self.target_network_params))]

        # This gradient will be provided by the critic network
        self.action_gradient = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.a_dim])

        # Combine the gradients here
        self.unnormalized_actor_gradients = tf.gradients(
            self.scaled_out, self.network_params, -self.action_gradient)
        self.actor_gradients = list(map(lambda x: tf.math.divide(x, self.batch_size), self.unnormalized_actor_gradients))

        # Optimization Op
        self.optimize = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(self.learning_rate).\
            apply_gradients(zip(self.actor_gradients, self.network_params))

        self.num_trainable_vars = len(
            self.network_params) + len(self.target_network_params)

    def create_actor_network(self):
        inputs = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, self.s_dim])
        net = tflearn.fully_connected(inputs, 400)
        net = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(net)
        net = tflearn.activations.relu(net)
        net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 300)
        net = tflearn.layers.normalization.batch_normalization(net)
        net = tflearn.activations.relu(net)
        # Final layer weights are init to Uniform[-3e-3, 3e-3]
        w_init = tflearn.initializations.uniform(minval=-0.003, maxval=0.003)
        out = tflearn.fully_connected(
            net, self.a_dim, activation='tanh', weights_init=w_init)
        # Scale output to -action_bound to action_bound
        scaled_out = tf.multiply(out, self.action_bound)
        return inputs, out, scaled_out

    def train(self, inputs, a_gradient):
        self.sess.run(self.optimize, feed_dict={
            self.inputs: inputs,
            self.action_gradient: a_gradient
        })

    def predict(self, inputs):
        return self.sess.run(self.scaled_out, feed_dict={
            self.inputs: inputs
        })

    def predict_target(self, inputs):
        return self.sess.run(self.target_scaled_out, feed_dict={
            self.target_inputs: inputs
        })

    def update_target_network(self):
        self.sess.run(self.update_target_network_params)

    def get_num_trainable_vars(self):
        return self.num_trainable_vars
```

When I call it once it does not give any error, however in the second time it gives an error. For example

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    actor1 = ActorNetwork(sess, 1, 2, 1, 0.01, 0.003, 200)
    actor2 = ActorNetwork(sess, 1, 2, 1, 0.01, 0.003, 200)
```

I get the following error for only actor2:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

It has something to do with None value in the lambda function. But, why does it not provide an error for the first time?

Edit: Stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-2323bc1d5028> in <module>()
      1 with tf.Session() as sess:
      2     actor1 = ActorNetwork(sess, 1, 2, 1, 0.01, 0.003, 200)
----> 3     actor2 = ActorNetwork(sess, 1, 2, 1, 0.01, 0.003, 200)

3 frames
<ipython-input-1-895268594a81> in __init__(self, sess, state_dim, action_dim, action_bound, learning_rate, tau, batch_size)
     48         self.unnormalized_actor_gradients = tf.gradients(
     49             self.scaled_out, self.network_params, -self.action_gradient)
---> 50         self.actor_gradients = list(map(lambda x: tf.math.divide(x, self.batch_size), self.unnormalized_actor_gradients))
     51 
     52         # Optimization Op

<ipython-input-1-895268594a81> in <lambda>(x)
     48         self.unnormalized_actor_gradients = tf.gradients(
     49             self.scaled_out, self.network_params, -self.action_gradient)
---> 50         self.actor_gradients = list(map(lambda x: tf.math.divide(x, self.batch_size), self.unnormalized_actor_gradients))
     51 
     52         # Optimization Op

/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/util/dispatch.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    178     """Call target, and fall back on dispatchers if there is a TypeError."""
    179     try:
--> 180       return target(*args, **kwargs)
    181     except (TypeError, ValueError):
    182       # Note: convert_to_eager_tensor currently raises a ValueError, not a

/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/ops/math_ops.py in divide(x, y, name)
    323     return DivideDelegateWithName(x, name) / y
    324   else:
--> 325     return x / y
    326 
    327 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

EDIT-2: From the suggestion, I wrote in TF 2.x. This actually eliminated the error. But are these two networks the same?

```
class ActorNetwork(object):
  def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, action_bound, learning_rate, tau, batch_size):
    self.state_dim = state_dim
    self.action_dim = action_dim
    self.action_bound = action_bound
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.tau  = tau
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(self.learning_rate)

    #actor network
    self.inputs, self.out, self.scaled_out = self.create_actor_network()
    self.actor_model = keras.Model(inputs=self.inputs, outputs=self.scaled_out, name='actor_network')
    self.network_params = self.actor_model.trainable_variables

    #target actor network
    self.target_inputs, self.target_out, self.target_scaled_out = self.create_actor_network()
    self.target_actor_model = keras.Model(inputs=self.target_inputs, outputs=self.target_scaled_out, name='target_actor_network')
    self.target_network_params = self.target_actor_model.trainable_variables


  def create_actor_network(self):
    inputs = Input(shape = (self.state_dim,), batch_size = None, name = "actor_input_state")

    net = layers.Dense(400, name = 'actor_dense_1a')(inputs)
    net = layers.BatchNormalization()(net)
    net = layers.Activation(activation=tf.nn.relu)(net)

    net = layers.Dense(300, name = 'actor_dense_1b')(net)
    net = layers.BatchNormalization()(net)
    net = layers.Activation(activation=tf.nn.relu)(net)

    # net = layers.Dense(20, name = 'actor_dense_1c')(net)
    # net = layers.BatchNormalization()(net)
    # net = layers.Activation(activation=tf.nn.relu)(net)

    # net = layers.Dense(10, name = 'actor_dense_1d')(net)
    # net = layers.BatchNormalization()(net)
    # net = layers.Activation(activation=tf.nn.relu)(net)
    
    w_init = tf.random_uniform_initializer(minval=-0.003, maxval=0.003, seed=None)
    out = layers.Dense(self.action_dim, activation='tanh', name = 'actor_dense_2', kernel_initializer = w_init)(net)
    scaled_out = tf.multiply(out, self.action_bound, name = "actions_scaling")
    return inputs, out, scaled_out
  
  def update_target_network(self):
    self.update_target_network_params = [self.target_network_params[i].assign(tf.multiply(self.network_params[i], self.tau) + tf.multiply(self.target_network_params[i], 1-self.tau)) for i in range(len(self.target_network_params))]
  
  def train(self, inputs, a_gradient):
    with tf.GradientTape() as self.tape:
      self.prediction = self.actor_model(inputs)
    self.unnormalized_actor_gradients = self.tape.gradient(self.prediction, self.network_params, output_gradients = -a_gradient)
    self.actor_gradients = list(map(lambda x: tf.math.divide(x, self.batch_size), self.unnormalized_actor_gradients))
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(self.actor_gradients, self.network_params))
    
  def predict(self, inputs):
    return self.actor_model(inputs)

  def predict_target(self, inputs):
    return self.target_actor_model(inputs)
```

Comment: Please add a stack trace of the error.

Comment: @jdehesa Added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```py
self.network_params = tf.trainable_variables()
```

And this is also most definitely going to cause you a problem:

```py
self.target_network_params = tf.trainable_variables()[
    len(self.network_params):]
```

The problem is that you are creating both models in the same TensorFlow graph. When you get `tf.trainable_variables()`, you are getting all trainable variables in the graph. The first time around, those are just the variables if the models you just created with `self.create_actor_network()`. But the second time, it will include the variables of the second `ActorNetwork` *and* the variables from the first one. Obviously, there are no gradients between the variables of the first network and the output of the second network, so `tf.gradients` produces some `None` results that then cause the error. The simplest solution would be to put each network in a different graph, for example:

```py
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph1, tf.Session() as sess1:
    actor1 = ActorNetwork(sess1, 1, 2, 1, 0.01, 0.003, 200)
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph2, tf.Session() as sess2:
    actor2 = ActorNetwork(sess2, 1, 2, 1, 0.01, 0.003, 200)
```

You could also do this from inside the class, which would be safer, although you would not be able to create the session beforehand:

```py
def __init__(self, state_dim, action_dim, action_bound, learning_rate, tau, batch_size):
    self.graph = tf.Graph()
    with self.graph.as_default():  # Add at the beginning of all methods
        self.sess = tf.Session()
        # ...
```

However, if you want to have both models within the same graph, you will need to change your code further to avoid using `tf.trainable_variables. You can for example keep track of the variables yourself:

```py
def create_actor_network(self):
    all_vars = []  # list of model variables
    inputs = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, self.s_dim])
    net = tflearn.fully_connected(inputs, 400)
    # Save layer variables
    all_vars.append(net.W)
    all_vars.append(net.b)
    # ...
    return inputs, out, scaled_out, all_vars  # Return variable list
```

The module [`tflearn.variables`](https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/0.3.2/tflearn/variables.py) offers some helpers to simplify this, although nothing too sophisticated. In any case, I would advise against using TFLearn if you can avoid it, since it is unmaintained and is superseded by Keras (where you would just need to use `.weights` / `.trainable_weights`).

Comment: Hi, following your suggestions, I wrote the code in TF 2.0. Can you have a look and let me know if they are actually doing the same?

Comment: @kosa That looks good as far as I can tell, unless I'm missing some detail I think it should be the same as you had with TFLearn. I'm not sure if the last `scaled_out = tf.multiply(...)` is ok like that or should better be a `Multiply` or `Lambda` Keras layer, not sure if it makes a difference. Keras also offers some utilities like [`summary`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#summary) to inspect the structure of your model and check number of parameters, sizes, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the summary tool to check for the parameters and visualize the layers. Why is it wrong to use tf.multiply(...)?

Comment: @kosa As I said I'm not sure if it makes a difference at all, probably not, with a layer it will appear as an element of the model structure (e.g. with `summary`), but since there are no weights or anything involved in the operation I think that may be the only practical difference. If the model compilation and training don't complain then it must be right.